# Restarting a thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am creating an application that allows a user to scan an ID badge which will start a thread that counts down from 10.  If another user scans their badge I'd like to restart the thread method back to the beginning.  I have the thread as a class variable.  When the user scans their badge I check to see if the thread is running I add their name to a list and restart the countdown if it is running.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Real questions have answers. "Any suggestions?" is not a real question. If you want to start a discussion, you will need to go to a regular forum.

Comment: I've tried th.abort and th.start which does not work.  From what I've researched the best method is to create a new thread but I'm not sure this will work for my project as the user can scan multiple times and I'd have to keep track of all of these threads

Comment: "Check if the thread is running" is already a bug, that's an inevitable threading race.  There is no point in burning up a thread to just count and risk bugs like that.  Use a timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a thread finished it's work it cannot be started again. You can create a new thread or use a thread pool.

If you are not stuck with old versions on .NET you should avoid using threads directly and switch to modern abstractions such as Task.

Comment: Thanks!  I created a new thread and just set it to the class variable and that worked.